# explorer lands on "deserted" planet, accidentally infects and kills local life forms

Tags: story-identification

I think he's a human astronaut.  His boots have germs he is not aware of, which prove fatal to the aliens.  It might be by Arthur C. Clarke.

Comment: There is a lot of guidance in [this post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to help you describe the story you're looking for in more detail - you can [edit] in anything else you remember.

Comment: Vaguely reminiscent of Clarke's "Before Eden", which was the answer to [this other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37331/short-story-about-how-2-astronauts-who-stop-for-lunch-unknowingly-destroy-the-on/37333#37333). Could that be the one you're thinking of?

Comment: That's it!  I just read it.  It's a wonderful cautionary tale.  I thank you for pointing it out to me.